# For loop to swap two elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say i have a shuffled deck of cards in an array

> S,H,D,C are the suits and 1,2,3.... are the ranks
>
> FYI, T means 10 so ST means Spade of 10.

```
HK  C2  C8  CQ  S3  SJ  S4  D2  HQ  H9  HT  DT  ST  
H2  H3  SA  CA  HJ  S9  S6  S8  H8  H6  C7  D7  CJ  
H7  C9  DQ  DA  C5  D4  D6  D9  SK  DJ  CK  DK  SQ  
D5  HA  D3  S2  H4  S5  C3  D8  CT  S7  C6  C4  H5
```

and i want to sort it according to its suit and rank such that it becomes

```
S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  ST  SJ  SQ  SK  SA  
H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  HT  HJ  HQ  HK  HA  
D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  DT  DJ  DQ  DK  DA  
C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  CT  CJ  CQ  CK  CA
```

So far, i have tried using Array.sort method to first change it to

```
Arrays.sort(arr); 

C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  CA  CJ  CK  CQ  CT  
D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  DA  DJ  DK  DQ  DT  
H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9  HA  HJ  HK  HQ  HT  
S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  SA  SJ  SK  SQ  ST
```

Next, in my swap method, I implemented a for loop to swap the 8th and 12th element of the array. My question is that i am seeing some formula such that in every single row, i have to swap the 8th and 12th element of the array. However, my for loop can only swap the 1st row as shown below:

```
          int x = 8;
          int y = 12;
                
          for(int k = 0;  k < 13 ;k++)
          {
              String temp = arr[x];
              arr[x] = arr[y];
              arr[y] = temp;
          }
```

this way, i am able to swap my first row to:

```
C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  CT  CJ  CK  CQ  CA
```

I am thinking that since every suit has 13 cards (e.g suit C will take 0-12 index of an array, suit D will take 13-25 index of an array..), I need to make an integer x = 8 and y = 12 and then increase them by 13 after every successful swap so that i can swap the other rows as well. However, i am stuck and unable to figure out a way.

so by adding another for loop:

```
              for(int k = 0;  k < 13 ;k++)
              {
                  String temp = str[i+13];
                  str[i+13] = str[j+13];
                  str[j+13] = temp;
              }
```

i am able to change the second row of element into

```
D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  DT  DJ  DK  DQ  DA
```

Is there a more dynamic way to do this such as nested for loop? Thanks

Comment: Go for a 2-dimensional array instead of just 1 dimension

Comment: ``Arrays.sort`` is good. Just provide a custom ``Comparator`` to override the default ordering implemented in ``String``.

Comment: Sorry, i am not allowed to use comparator and 2d array so the only solution i thought of is a for loop..

Comment: Beyond the basic array thing: dont represent cards as Strings. Create two Enums, one for Suit, one for Rank, both could implement comparable. Then create a card class that has a suit and rank field. Create helpful abstractions. Otherwise you have to repeat complicated code all over the place, because dealing with the elements you need to deal with ... is so complicated. Because you are missing these helpful abstractions.

Comment: When I hear _"Sorry, i am not allowed to use comparator"_, I see in my mind a surgeon that says _"sorry, no scalpel to me. I must use a swiss knife."_ Do not listen to a professor that forbids you to do things the correct way.

Comment: @spi it could just be a step-by-step exercise in doing it the right way, with this step being about learning how to swap elements of an array. Later steps will teach them other things, until they reach the appropriate solution. It's useful to learn how to swap array elements for many purposes.

Comment: @JanB you don't need a loop to swap array elements. What you are doing here is repeated swapping elements 8 and 12. Every second time you swap these two elements, they get back to their original position. You do this 13 times. You are "lucky" that 13 is an odd number so you end up with an actual swap by the end of it. Just remove the loop, and swap it once.

Comment: Oh yes.. you are right. I removed the for loops and jus looped the swap 4 times and everytime it looped i increase my x and y integers by 13. this way i am able to swap all 4 rows of my cards with just 1 for loop without using for loop to swap the elements. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JanB Small FYI: you've now swapped `T` and `A`, but your `Q` and `K` need to swap as well.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that. I was just giving one example of my problem.. Thanks for the info though!